# Installing Ubuntu Software Applications in Qubes OS

Tags: software-rec, libreoffice, qubes

Is it possible to install the Ubuntu Software Applications, such as LibreOffice and others in Qubes OS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu itself can be installed into Qubes, but due to licensing concerns it requires one of the following:

1. Installing Ubuntu separately as an HVM
2. Use of the [Qubes Builder](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/templates/ubuntu/) which will generate an Ubuntu OS template that is more flexible.

---

Qubes does have a Debian OS template that is similar to Ubuntu in many ways and can be easily installed from dom0 like so:

```
sudo qubes-dom0-update qubes-template-debian-8
```

After template installation you can update it then begin installing apps such as LibreOffice:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

The Debian template is somewhat on the minimal side in terms of pre-installed packages. If you wish to have a conventional desktop assortment of apps and utilities installed (including LibreOffice) you can select one of the desktop environment options (like Gnome or KDE) using the `tasksel` command in the template.

As for installing actual Ubuntu packages in Debian, it may be possible with some programs but YMMV. Except for the Linux kernel package, this is a generic Ubuntu/Debian issue; kernel installations for templates are handled with dom0 package management.

Answer (score 0):

Qubes is based on the Xen hypervisor, therefore it distinguishes between the host (Dom0) and guest (DomU). Installing software on Dom0 brakes the security model of Qubes and renders it useless, so it should be avoided.

Instead install programs in DomU OS's, such as Ubuntu. These are known as *template VMs*. To do that, [follow this guide](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/software-update-domu/#installing-software-in-templatevms):

> NOTE:* Ubuntu is a Debian based OS, so they share package types (.deb) and package managers (apt). You can install any .deb package on either Ubuntu or Debian. You will not need to distinguish between Ubuntu or Debian in Qubes, because the inner workings of the guest VMs becom opaque due the templated nature of running applications in Qubes.

### To permanently install new software in a TemplateVM:

1. Start the TemplateVM.
2. Start either a terminal (e.g. gnome-terminal)
   or a dedicated software management application, such as
   gpk-application.
3. Install software as normally instructed inside that
   operating system (e.g. sudo dnf install <PACKAGE_NAME> on Fedora,
   sudo apt install <PACKAGE_NAME> on Debian).
4. Shut down the TemplateVM.
5. Restart all TemplateBasedVMs based on the TemplateVM so the changes can take effect.
6. (Optional) In the relevant emplateBasedVMs’ Qube Settings, go to the Applications tab, select the new application(s) from the list, and press OK. These new shortcuts will appear in the Applications Menu.